# How to use custom selector of collectionview with maui on Windows machine?

Tags: xaml, maui, collectionview

How can I use a custom selector in a collectionview using maui on Windows machine with parameter `SelectionMode="Multiple"`, or how can I hide it?

The xaml file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiCollectionMVVM.MainPage">
        <ContentPage.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                            Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                                    
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ContentPage.Resources>
        
        <VerticalStackLayout >
    
            <CollectionView x:Name="StagiaireCollectionView"
                            SelectionMode="Multiple"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding students}" >
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
                            <Label Grid.Column="0"
                                   Text="{Binding Name}" x:Name="TxtUserPrimary" FontSize="12" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            <ImageButton Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ImgLicence"   VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                <ImageButton.Source>
                                    <FontImageSource
                                        FontFamily="IconsInscriptionStagiaires"
                                        Glyph="&#xE800;"
                                        Size="10"
                                        Color="Gray">
                                    </FontImageSource>
                                </ImageButton.Source>
                            </ImageButton>
                            <ImageButton Grid.Column="2" x:Name="ImgOnedrive" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                <ImageButton.Source>
                                    <FontImageSource
                                                FontFamily="IconsInscriptionStagiaires"
                                                Glyph="&#xE800;"
                                                Size="20"
                                                Color="Gray"
                                                >
                                    </FontImageSource>
                                </ImageButton.Source>
                            </ImageButton>
                            <ImageButton Grid.Column="3" x:Name="ImgFolder" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                <ImageButton.Source>
                                    <FontImageSource
                                        FontFamily="IconsInscriptionStagiaires"
                                        Glyph="&#xE800;"
                                        Size="20"
                                        Color="Gray">
                                    </FontImageSource>
                                </ImageButton.Source>
                            </ImageButton>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
    
        </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The result

[image]

I can customize the color of the selected line (see my code) but not the select image and the place used for this image.

As we can see there is a place with an image (white) that is displayed.

How can I hide or customize this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the source code about the CollectionView for maui on windows. It is the ListView that implements the ListViewBase.

And the ListViewBase has the
[IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.ismultiselectcheckboxenabled?view=winrt-22621). You can set the property as false and it will hide the checkbox place.

Just put the following code in the **MainPage.xaml.cs**:

```
    protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if WINDOWS
            var listviewbase = StagiaireCollectionView.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewBase;
            listviewbase.IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled = false;
#endif
      }
```